# Two Rails project share the same database...how to make everyone happy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration

I have **project A** in my local machine. Sometime ago I started **project B** by copying and pasting project A folder.  Think of project B as project A plus two days of development.

Both A and B have their separate deployment and staging servers on different machines, and therefore do not share databases. Also they have their different correspondent repos. This problem is confined to my local machine.

When I created more models in Project B everything continued to work OK, but when I tried to replicate the same in project A, I got the database error 'relation already exists'. Since they both share the same database, I couldn't run any migration on *Project A*

I foolishly forgot to create a new database when I copied prject A folder into project B. **This is my problem now**.

I have succesfully rollback the migrations I run in project B, so the database is in agreement with project A migration history.

I'd like to "detach" project B from the database and to setup their own database. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

How about, running rake db:drop on project B to delete the database, then edit Project B's database.yml to have a different name for the database than Project A's, then run rake db:setup to recreate the database on both projects with different names?  Since you copied pasted A's folder you also copied A's database.yml thus ending with 2 apps and 1 database.

Comment: Running `rake db:drop` on project B would also delete project A's database since they're same currently.